# selection in datagridview comboboxcolumn display image in another cell c# windows form

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have load my combobox with the image id and image name from the sql database. I want it if we select any image name in the combobox, the image with that image name will be displayed at another cell. Below code is how i load my datagridview combobox column with data from the database.[here is the table from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W351x.png) can anyone help me? [here is the columns in the datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHhah.png)

`

```
string constr = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-909N2K6\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=project1;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT shapeID, shapeCode FROM shapeTable order by shapeCode asc ", conn))
                {
                    //Fill the DataTable with records from Table.
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    //Insert the Default Item to DataTable.
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

                    //Assign DataTable as DataSource, Shape is the comboboxcolumn name that i have add in the datagridview column.


                    this.Shape.DisplayMember = "shapeCode";
                    this.Shape.ValueMember = "shapeID";
                    this.Shape.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
```

`

[here is the ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHUI3.png)

i already tried using this code, but i have problem with requiring the comboboxcolumn selected value and the code does not work.

Edited : i have required the way to retrieve the combobox column value, now i dont know the right way to display the image column with the image that belong to the combobox column value.

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            // This fires the cell value changed handler below
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell Shape = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10];
        if (Shape.Value != null)
        {
            // the code to display image based on the value retrieve from the combobox column
            dataGridView1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. What's `this.Shape` in the code? What does this code do? When this code is executed? Have you tried writing code for the functionality you want? What's the issue you are facing there?

Comment: i've already add more details of my problem. Does it help to understand more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I've already got the answer. [here are the example of ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzGRJ.png)

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                // This fires the cell value changed handler below
                dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }
        }
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell Shape = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10]; //retrieve the datagridview combobox column value
        if (e.ColumnIndex == Shape.ColumnIndex) // this the code where i use to display the image in the datagridviewimage column
                {
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                    {
                            using (SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT shapeImage FROM shapeTable WHERE shapeCode = @shapeCode", conn))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                   
                                        cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shapeCode", Shape.Value);
                                        conn.Open();
                                        byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmmd.ExecuteScalar();
                                        conn.Close();
                                        Image img = byteArrayToImage(bytes);                                   
                                        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                                        row.Cells[11].Value = img;
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                }
                            }
                            dataGridView1.Invalidate();  
                    }
                }
    }

    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```